# RoutingError error about Knock]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I'm using a namespace like below. When I access `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user_token`, 
I got a RoutingError error like this. What I doing wrong.

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::Knock):
>     app/controllers/api/v1/user_token_controller.rb:3:in `<module:V1>'
>     app/controllers/api/v1/user_token_controller.rb:2:in`'
>     app/controllers/api/v1/user_token_controller.rb:1:in `'

Here is my code. ⬇︎

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, format: 'json' do
    namespace :v1, format: 'json' do
      post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
    end
  end
end
```

users_token_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UserTokenController < Knock::AuthTokenController
    end
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Knock::Authenticable
end
```

Comment: run `rake routes` and share..

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon its a Ruby constant lookup error. The routes are irrelevant.

Comment: that's right. Im using a gem called "knock" for authentication.https://github.com/nsarno/knock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UserTokenController < ::Knock::AuthTokenController
    end
  end
end
```

`::` tells Ruby to lookup`Knock` in the top level instead of the current module nesting (`API::V1`).

See [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html) and [Avoid these traps when nesting Ruby modules](http://blog.honeybadger.io/avoid-these-traps-when-nesting-ruby-modules/) for an in depth explaination.